# Using CSS 3 transform -mouse hover not working properly for Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, transform

Here in the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5rgBe/1/)  dummy text are float and for  3d effect have used transform

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(15deg);
```

and on hover it pause the dummy text to float.

```
#flyDiv
    {
     width:720px; 
     height:420px;
     transform-origin: 50% 100%; 
     transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(15deg); 
     -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 10s; 
     -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%; 
     -webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(15deg);
}
```

Its wroking fine for firefox, but in chrome theres some problem sometimes its not pause on hover.

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5rgBe/1/)**